# Firebase: is possible to set a server-side timed deletion?

Tags: firebase

I'm developing a chat application based on Firebase. I would like to delete automatically every message after 24 hours. Is it possible to do it with Firebase? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to delete every message after 24 hours even if is a user is logged on and viewing them?

Comment: @Jay yes, I would like to do so

Comment: Firebase doesn't have server side logic in that sense. However, you can simulate the deletion. With each post, keep track of when the post was created. Whenever any user logs on, it can simply check for any posts older than 24 hours and delete them.

Comment: Thanks @Jay, I will do so ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Firebase purpose it to integrate automatition. It serves as a fast way to store, retrieve and serve JSON data across devices in real time. An idea would be to: 1. get the time the user signed in 2. compare dates 3. send a desired operation to Firebase.

Eventually you can create a server-side or Node snippet that would periodically contact your Firebase database and perform such tasks.

Comment: Thank you so much @Roko, is really a pity that Firebase doesn't have server side logic, I hope they will work on it!

Comment: @RadamesFabioSoulmathe sure! would be nice to see appear in the Rulesets some way to give an instruction that could allow such automated tasks. We'll stay tuned and see what this amazing service has to offer in the future!