# How to delete data from user automatically with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I created an application and use Firebase as backend. In my application  User can upload  images and these images should be deleted after one week from the database. I don't know how I can delete stuff automatically and after an amount of time because the code is running on the devices of the user and maybe there will be hundreds of user. Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve that please ? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase: is possible to set a server-side timed deletion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36068791/firebase-is-possible-to-set-a-server-side-timed-deletion)

Comment: Please see this almost duplicate question [How to have Firebase automatically delete values older than 30 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851144/how-to-have-firebase-automatically-delete-values-older-than-30-minutes). There is a LOT of really good content here on stack overflow, so doing some searches for the topic you are asking about reveals a number of answers.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Firebase doesn't have support for adding a parameter to a query. You could try adding Cloud Function with a trigger to run a delete query when something is written to the database. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events

Comment: The article is a bit confusing can you give a little example please to understand the basic. I never heard something about Clound functions

Comment: @Morphley This is an odd answer and doesn't really address the question. Adding a parameter to a query doesn't appear to have anything to do with automatically deleting data. Also, while trigging a cloud function is a direction, the link provided is one for trigging a cloud function by a change in storage. The OP wants to delete from storage so a more appropriate answer would be levering a cron job. More information [HTTP Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) and [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron)