# How to have Firebase automatically delete values older than 30 minutes

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a Swift/iOS application that creates/holds data something like this:

buyer_name: "john@gmail.com"
seller_name: "tom@gmail.com"
price: "20.00"
product: "baseball cards"
timestamp: 1498677314931

I am taking the timestamp with

FIRServerValue.timestamp()

I would like to create some kind of timeout, where it deletes firebase data older than 30 minutes, as per the timestamp. The problem is that I would not like to do it directly from the app, as the user could technically logout after 5 minutes. I would like to do it from some other independent process.

So, I'm wondering if this can be done automatically through Firebase, or if I have to deploy some other application that does this continuously on an EC2 instance, or if there is some other method?

Comment: This might be useful: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Cloud Functions for Firebase and set up a cron job that runs, say, every five minutes and checks for timestamps older than 30 minutes.

As Will commented, that blog post is useful to learn about scheduling Cloud Functions. Here are some other useful resources to get you started:

[Getting Started with Cloud Functions for Firebase - YouTube](https://youtu.be/EvV9Vk9iOCQ?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM)

[Cloud Functions for Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)

[Cloud Functions Samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples)

[Timing Cloud Functions for Firebase using an HTTP Trigger and Cron - YouTube](https://youtu.be/CbE2PzvAMxA)