# Firebase Cloud System sending recurring messages?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there any possibility in Firebase Cloud System to configure messages to be sended for example in a 10 minutes basis without using an external server?

Comment: I do not think this "cron job" functionality is possible.

Comment: What a pity if this is true... it would make things so much easier :)

Comment: There's a LOT of info here on stack overflow about automatic tasks and cron jobs. Doing a search for [firebase]cron will reveal a number of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have Firebase automatically delete values older than 30 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851144/how-to-have-firebase-automatically-delete-values-older-than-30-minutes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron jobs are possible with Firebase Cloud Functions. But you'll have to integrate it with Google App Engine ( at least for now, anyway ).

Check out this [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html) by Abe Haskins of the Firebase team.

[This](https://github.com/firebase/functions-cron) should help you too.