# How to delete data older than 30 minutes on Firebase with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is there any simple and free way to delete data older than 30 minutes?

even if the user's app is terminated

so its completely independent from the device's timing

thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851144/how-to-have-firebase-automatically-delete-values-older-than-30-minutes

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write a cron job using App engine which triggers a function to delete previous data.
See this for example :
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/quickstart

This is a simple example project here : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/hello-world/standard

if you clone this you will find an app.js file , you will have to write the function which will delete the data according to your logic.